# kendo-ui web: How to change the position of the details column

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-ui

The situation: I have build a Grid with kendo-ui web (in ASP.NET MVC 3) with the details feature. So the first column has the controls to show/open or hide/close the details views. This works fine, no problems.
The quest/problem: I have to move this first column, so that it is the 3rd or 4th column. But before I start to change the source code of kendo-ui web:
Does anyone know how to do it without changing the source code?

FYI: I have only the opensource kendo-ui web!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the position of the toggle expand/collapse icon is not supported out of the box. I think it can be implemented easily without modifying the source code. You need to handle the `dataBound` event of the grid and move the expand/collapse column (`<col>`, `<th>` and `<td>`). Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/exawot/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But finding the index by column header content is not working well. You can see it by paging in your demo. So I removed the index finding and set a constant value for the index. That works for me. But your tip saved me a lot of time.